# how to get venues by categories wise from four square api

Tags: iphone, foursquare

I am integrating foursquare api into my application using this [foursquareintegration](https://github.com/anka/bw_examples/tree/master/FoursquareIntegration).

i am getting near venues.

But my requirement is i need to display streets&skylines in red green color,places in blue color news(weather,traffic...) in yellow color and Events(sports,Concerts/Shows/Fairs....) in red colors.

is it possible to differentiate result getting from four squire api,if it is then how can i done this.

If not how can i get venues like this can any one please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The foursquare API only returns places and events. It doesn't return streets/skylines or news. The place and event objects are structured differently so it should be easy to distinguish between them.

https://developer.foursquare.com